# Caching webservice calls on Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, web-services

I have a Flex 3 application that makes a call to a webservice. That webservice calls returns a 2 Mb file that flex reads and parses. The problem is that it takes sometimes 45 seconds. I was wondering if there is a way to cache the response form the webservice? So the next time I load the flash movie it doesn't have to re-download the full file but just the updated data.

Thank you for any help

Yves

Answer (score 0):

Well you *can* code something to let you map a request to a response, if you can uniquely identify a request based on parameters. Then call a method like getWebServiceResult(x,y,z) which checks if a result for {x,y,z} is already found.

There may be functionality for caching built into Flex though, so I'd double-check that first.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you own that web service, try using http cache header to inform the browser for how long it can hold the response in cache. Then you wouldn't have to change anything in your flex client.